# How to change the name of the iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone

This question has been asked before and I did followed the instructions but my application crashed. I want to change my application name before deployment. I clicked on Project and then selected rename. Everything got renamed. When I ran the application the application crashed. I think it was because the app was not able to locate the images and sound files from the resources folder.

What is the recommended way of performing the rename to the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to change the name of your xcode project? This is difficult, but not impossible. If the end result you are trying to achieve is to name your app differently, just set the display name for it in the Info.plist

Comment: I just want to change the name that displays unders the icon. I tried to change the bundle name but for some reason the app crashes.

Comment: It's no longer true that it's difficult to change a project's name. The Project menu in the current version of Xcode has a **Rename...** item; all you have to do to change your project name is select that item and enter the new name in a dialog.

Comment: actually I made a new project and copied all the files to that project and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `CFBundleDisplayName = "Your name";` in your InfoPlist.strings file. This will enable you to localized the app name.